# に particle usage in this sentence

Tags: particle-に

The sentence:

私に verb (for example: 行ってほしくない) +　ほしくない

This means "(someone) don't want me to go"

Can anyone give me a bit of an insight why the に particle is used here. How I think of the に particle is as follows. When using the に particle, the next verb  (after the に)　acts towards whatever preceeds the に particle, in this case, it acts on 私 which very literally translates to "don't want/wish to come to me".

I can't seen to understand why the に particle can be used in this manner. Any help will be appreciated.

Addendum: 
A bit of an unreasonable question, but I thought I'd ask anyways. Can anyone recommend me some material/ video that explains all the usages of に particle. I found https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-particle-ni-clear-up-all-doubts-you-may-have/ but I don't see any explanation of に particle used in the fashion of the sentences above.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> When using the に particle, the next verb (after the に)　acts towards whatever preceeds the に particle...

which suggests that you think of に as meaning 'to' in some sense. But I would say that it can just as often mean 'from'.

> 田中さん**に**本を買ってもらった。
>   Tanaka bought me a book.
>    Literally: I received book buying **from** Tanaka.
>
> 田中さん**に**寿司を食べられた。
>   Tanaka ate my sushi (and I'm miffed about it).
>   Literally: I received sushi eating **from** Tanaka.

Your sentence works the same way:

> 私**に**行ってほしくない
>   *somebody*  doesn't want me to go.
>   Literally: *Somebody* doesn't want (the act of) going **from** me.

Maybe somebody has a clever way of fusing these two seemingly opposite meanings (to/from) into a glorious whole, but I'm happy to think of them separately and let context tell me which meaning to apply.

Aside: I'm no expert but my understanding is that using ほしい with a third person is wrong, and that in this case you should use something like もらいたがっている instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose context is really the best way to tell whether the に particle indicates "to" or "from". Giving an example sentence, 田中に行ってほしくない can either mean "don't want to go to tanaka's place" or it can mean "don't want tanaka to go"